# Appcelerator Titanium using common options for labels

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

```
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var YPos = 30;   

    var Label1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            left : 0,
            top : YPos ,
            width: "50%",
            backgroundColor: "blue",
            height: 20,
            text: i.toString(),
            textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
        });

    var Label2 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            left : "50%",
            top : YPos ,
            width: "50%",
            backgroundColor: "blue",
            height: 20,
            text: i.toString(),
            textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
        });

     YPos += 30;
};
```

I would not like to use again and again the following block of code in loop.

```
width: "50%",
backgroundColor: "blue",
height: 20,
text: i.toString(),
textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
```

I am using Alloy. 
I assigned as class as below

```
var Label2 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            left : "50%",
            top : YPos ,
            class:"CommonPro"
        });
```

in .tss file

```
    ".CommonPro":
   {
           width: "50%",
           backgroundColor: "blue",
           height: 20,
           text: "Bla Bla",
           textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
    }
```

Also i used to `className:"CommonPro"` properties for label but nothing changed.

How approach must i try?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
var labelOptions = {
     left : 0,
     width: "50%",
     backgroundColor: "blue",
     height: 20,
     textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
     top  : 0,
     text : ''
};
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var YPos = 30;   
    labelOptions.top = YPos;
    labelOptions.string = i.toString();
    var Label1 = Ti.UI.createLabel(labelOptions);
    var Label2 = Ti.UI.createLabel(labelOptions);
    YPos += 30;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

class only supports when you use in xml file so try to create a common json object and pass that into label or create function which returns a common label object.